# Django - Redirect depending on variable

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have extended the Site model and I would like to add a parameter to it and call it Activate Under Construction page.

So far it's pretty easy, what I would like to do is that when that field is True, I would like that every url except the /admin/ is redirected to the /underconstruction/ View.... How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lo,
Ara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you live with restarting your server to change said value?  It would seem you could do a conditional redirect in urls.py (i.e. define the url_patterns variable with conditional values, similar to how some folks do things with if DEBUG, add some extra url patterns);

```
if (config.UNDER_CONSTRUCTION):
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/$', admin),
    url(r'^underconstruction/', 'something.views.underconstruction',name='underconstruction')
    url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='underconstruction', permanent=False), name='uc')
) #defintely recommend making sure permanent not set to True
else:
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ... #normal patterns go here
```

Otherwise it seems you could possibly overload RedirectView but that means that every request would need to check the variable and be routing accordingly)  I feel like there should be another way, but not thinking of it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I don't see any other way also, I looked around. Thanks a lot, Ara!